# Excel VBA: If A2="a","b","c",etc... then B2="aa"?

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

I'm attempting to take the text in each cell of column A and assign a value to each cell in column B depending on the text in column A. For example, I have a list of versions that are identified by four-letter abbreviations of cities, and all of those versions are regionally assigned to different factories to be produced. So let's say I have an "AUST", "DAFW", "HOUS", and more versions all assigned to the location of "ARLINGTON". How would I most concisely use VBA to automate that once I have all the versions plugged in? Something like

```
If A2="AUST" Then
B2="ARLINGTON"
ElseIf A2="DAFW" Then
B2="ARLINGTON"
```

I suppose something like this would work, however I can't believe that there's not a faster and more concise way. Does this make any sense? I've been pulling my hair out for about a week now trying to figure this out... Thanks for any help!

Comment: Not necessary... You can use dictionary.

Comment: Or you can simply use a `VLOOKUP` if VBA is not 100% required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done with excel formulas as well, though I always prefer to use VBA. This should work the way you want :

```
Sub yourFunk()

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

    arlington = Array("AUST", "DAFW", "HOUS")
    otherLocation = Array("XXXX", "YYYY", "ZZZZ")

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 2 To lastRow

        If stringIsInArray(ws.Cells(x, 1), arlington) Then
            ws.Cells(x, 2) = "ARLINGTON"
        ElseIf stringIsInArray(ws.Cells(x, 1), otherLocation) Then
            ws.Cells(x, 2) = "OTHER LOCATION"
        End If

    Next x


End Sub

Function stringIsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    stringIsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
End Function
```

If you need me to explain the code, please do let me know :)

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for... Thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't think to use an array... I'm a high school student that just started an internship at a printing company and you saved my butt!

Answer (score 1):

This is a little simpler using OR:

```
If A2="AUST" OR A2="DAFW" Then
  B2="ARLINGTON"
ElseIf A2 = "ABCD" OR A2 = "WZYZ" Then
  B2="SOMETHING"
'ETC...
```

However, if you are iterating over column A, the variable "A2" is strange. But I am not sure how you are doing this. Maybe supply more code and we can help you more.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is to use Dictionary.

Let's say, your data is present in the following range:

```
A2 = "AUST"
A3 = "DAFW"
```

Now, check this code:

```
'Needs reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
Sub Translate()
Dim dic As Dictionary
Dim i As Integer, sTmp As String

Set dic = New Dictionary
dic.Add "AUST", "ARLINGTON"
dic.Add "DAFW", "ARLINGTON"

For i = 2 To 3
    sTmp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & i)
    Debug.Print sTmp, "-", dic(sTmp)
Next

Set dic = Nothing

End Sub
```

Note: This code is just an example!

For further information please see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx