# Using Array Function to Alter Cell Values Based on Their Current Values?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I asked a  ([similar question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30110472/excel-vba-if-a2-a-b-c-etc-then-b2-aa/30110853#30110853) a few weeks ago and I tried to navigate my way to my new question's answer using it but I have not been able to. Basically what I want to do is this: I have data being copied from a one workbook and pasted into column A of a template workbook. After that, I want to alter the contents of those cells that I just pasted based on what is in the cell when I paste them. For example, one cell will be pasted and it will say "ALBY Total" and I want to automatically (using VBA) change the cell to say "ALBY." I tried to code it myself but couldn't get it to work. I don't get an error, but nothing happens. Here's an example of my code (there are a ton of arrays, so I won't give you all of them):

```
Sub TSA_Template_Creation_Macro()

Workbooks("TSA Template.xlsm").Activate

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

alby = Array("ALBY Total")
anch = Array("ANCH Total")
atlc = Array("ATLC Total")

lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To lastRow

    If stringIsInArray(ws.Cells(x, 1), alby) Then
        ws.Cells(x, 1) = "ALBY"
    ElseIf stringIsInArray(ws.Cells(x, 1), anch) Then
        ws.Cells(x, 1) = "ANCH (+office)"
    ElseIf stringIsInArray(ws.Cells(x, 1), atlc) Then
        ws.Cells(x, 1) = "ATLC"

 End If

Next x

End Sub

Function stringIsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
stringIsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > 0)
End Function
```

I'm fairly new to the world of VBA so it could very well be a simple fix. I've fiddled around with it but I have no idea how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you are manually pasting the values. If that's the case the following should work when run from the template workbook containing the values:

Sub TSA_Template_Creation_Macro()

lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For x = 1 To lastRow

```
If InStr(1, Cells(x, 1), "ALBY") Then
    Cells(x, 1) = "ALBY"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(x, 1), "ANCH") Then
    Cells(x, 1) = "ANCH (+office)"
ElseIf InStr(1, Cells(x, 1), "ATLC") Then
    Cells(x, 1) = "ATLC"
```

End If

Next x

End Sub

Comment: You, sir, are a champion! Thank you so much!!! Like I said, I'm a bit of a neophyte working an internship and you saved my butt. This is the best website in the world!